# Compare 2 method including comments trivia with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to perform comparison between 2 methods in c# code,
I found the `SyntaxNode.IsEquivalentTo`, but in case the methods are:

```
public void Method1()
{
    //hello
}
```

and

```
public void Method1()
{  
}
```

the return value is : `True`.

is there any other way with Rslyn API to perform comparison including comments trivia?? 
(and in the example above to get: False??)

(The reason i'm not using regular string comparison is that i wan't that spaces and new line will not count as difference, for example:

```
public void Method1()
{
    int i=1;
}
```

and

```
public void Method1(){

    int i=1  ;
}
```

will be equal.

Comment: Spaces, newlines and comments are all trivia. So I take it you want to compare equality including trivia but without whitespace trivias?

Comment: yes, all code and comments will be included. white spaces and extra new lines will be excluded

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this, **there is no built-in method to support such comparison, but it is easy to write one using syntax rewriters**.

The basic idea is very simple. Write a [`CSharpSyntaxRewriter`](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/9E165294.htm) that will remove all the non-comment trivia from both of the compared nodes and then compare the newly created nodes by using the built in [`IsEquivalentTo()`](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/5CDA147F.htm) method.

The below code does what you are looking for. To compare two nodes (`MethodDeclarationSyntax` in your case) just call:

```
firstNode.IsEquivalentToWithCommentsPreserved(secondNode);
```

Here is the implementation:

```
public static class SyntaxNodeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEquivalentToWithCommentsPreserved(this SyntaxNode syntaxNode, SyntaxNode otherNode)
    {
        var triviaRemover = new NonCommentTriviaRemover();
        return triviaRemover.Visit(syntaxNode)
               .IsEquivalentTo(triviaRemover.Visit(otherNode));
    }

    private class NonCommentTriviaRemover : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
    {
        private static readonly SyntaxTrivia EmptyTrivia = default(SyntaxTrivia);

        public override SyntaxTrivia VisitTrivia(SyntaxTrivia trivia)
        {
            return trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia) ||
                   trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia)
                ? trivia // Preserve comments by returning the original comment trivia.
                : EmptyTrivia; // Remove all other trivias.
        }
    }
}
```

*Keep in mind that this code does not ignore eventual differences in trivias in comments.* That means, these two versions of the methods will be considered as not being equivalent:

```
void Method()
{
    // Some comment.
}

void Method()
{
    // Some      comment.
}
```

Let me know if you maybe need to ignore these differences as well. I can then extend the solution to cover that case as well.

I quickly tried the solution on the following non-trivial example and it worked fine:

```
var firstCode =
@"
    // First comment.
    // Second comment.
    int x(int a)
    {
        // This is a comment.
        // And this as well.
        if (a == 1) // This also
        {
            return 0 ;
        }

        /*
            Multi line comment.
        */if(a == -5) return -10   ;

        if (a == 2)
                return 0 ;

        return 5;

    }
";

var secondCode =
@"
    // First comment.

    // Second comment.

    int x(int a)
    {

        // This is a comment.
        // And this as well.
                if    (a 
                == 1) // This also
        {
            return     0 ;
              }

        /*
            Multi line comment.
        */

        if(a == -5) return -10   ;

        if (a == 2) return 0 ;

        return 5;


    }
";

var firstMethod = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(firstCode).GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();
var secondMethod = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(secondCode).GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();

Console.WriteLine($"{firstMethod.IsEquivalentTo(secondMethod)}"); // Prints false.
Console.WriteLine($"{firstMethod.IsEquivalentToWithCommentsPreserved(secondMethod)}"); // Prints true.
```

Still, before using the code in the production it would be good to write proper unit test for it, null-checks etc. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If they need to be exactly the same, you could simply call `node.ToString()` on the nodes and compare the strings.

Comment: but i don't want that extra space or new line will count as difference, and with ToString() it will...